# pthread function "int" return codes as error string

Tags: c, error-handling, runtime-error, pthreads

Most, if not all, pthread functions return an `int` which the man pages typically describe as

> Upon successful completion, a value of zero shall be returned; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

What is the correct mechanism to convert these `int` return codes into human readable error strings? For example, with `errno` one could do `strerror(errono)`. Is there a pthread equivalent?

Comment: The example in the [man pthread_create](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) is showing how the errors are handled. TL;DR, yes these are compatible with `perror` and friends.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I'm somewhat surprised that the `handle_error_en` macro documented on that man page hasn't been implemented either as a macro in `pthread.h` or as a function

Comment: That macro is not "documented" in the sense of a macro provided by the system.  It is just part of an example.